# Logging into an external website with flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, flask, python-requests

I'm currently having some trouble with my flask webapp, where I have written it as below, but when I try to run the flask app, I run into a Bad Request Error. (The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand)

Essentially, I am trying to allow users to log in to an external website through the flask webapp

What is the cause of this error? Apologies if I am making a stupid mistake, I'm very new to flask.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request, redirect
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    username = request.form['username']
    pin = request.form['password']
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get("https://www.example.com/User/Login")
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    loginToken = soup.findAll(attrs={"name" : "__RequestVerificationToken"})[0]['value']
    #Create Login Payload
    login_payload = {
    "__RequestVerificationToken" : loginToken,
    "UserName" : username,
    "Password" : pin,
    "returnUrl" : "https://example.com/user-action/?action=login&returnUrl=https://www.example.com/User/Information",
    }
    #Post Login Payload
    r = s.post("https://www.example.com/Account/Login", data = login_payload)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return render_template('home.html')
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/home') #If login works, redirect to this page
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

In addition, if there are other resources that I could refer to with regards to allowing a user to log in to a external URL from the flask webapp as compared to the conventional tutorials that only show a user logging in to the flask webapp itself, do share it with me, thank you!

Comment: Please post the full error message that you're getting from Flask

Comment: The error message when I run ‘flask run’ from command prompt and load localhost:5000 is: Bad Request Error. The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: How are you accessing the web page? Do you just go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` in the browser?

Comment: yes, i used localhost:5000 to access it.

Comment: Now here's the question: how did you supply the `username` and `password` parameters? Your code expects them to be sent by a form: `username = request.form['username']; pin = request.form['password']`

Comment: i have a forms.py file

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint' s has two Http verbs `["POST", "GET"]`. You should specify your methods as below.

```
@app.route('/', methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def login():
   if request.method == "GET":
     #something do stuff
     return render_template("your_html_page")
   if request.method == "POST":
     #something do stuff
     return your_response, 200
```

**Edited Block**

```
@app.route('/', methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('login.html')
    if request.method == "POST":
        #same logic here
        if status_code == 200:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        return render_template('login.html')
```

Comment: unfortunately i still encounter 400 Bad Request Error

Comment: As @ForceBru said, In appearance you can' t pass form arguments when you entered into page on browser if you're not using Postman. Therefore you getting an error. If it was like like `'/username=mert&password=1234'` `request.args.get("username")` `request.args.get("password")`. It works request.args instead of request.form.

Comment: what should I have done instead/what can I change in my code? apologies for the many questions

Comment: Your welcome, your code should be like above. I hope it helps you.